# Get Sum of datagridview Column using Linq for a distinct ID

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms `Form1(DGV1 & DGV2)` and `Form2(DGV3 & DGV4)` with `Datagridview` controls on both the forms.

On `Form1` there is a button link to `Form2` where user can add rows to `Form1` `datagridview(DGV1)`. In `Form2 → (DGV3 and DGV4)`, there is a `checkbox` in the first column and the user can select only one row at a time.

There are two buttons on `Form2`: `Done` and `Add Items`

When user clicks on Add Items by selecting the rows one after another,the rows must be added to the `datagridview` on `Form1` and when Done button is clicked, `Form1` should be displayed with all the rows that are added.

I have achieved this.

The columns in `DGV1` and `DGV2` are

**DGV1 Columns**

```
Sno Desciption SellQty ItemID
----------------------------
 1    ABC       0         1 
 2    XYZ       0         2
```

**DGV2 Columns**

```
Sno BatchNo SellQty ItemID
----------------------------
1    123       10         1
2    528       20         2
1    568       30         1
2    522       40         2
```

During the loading of `Form1`, how can I get the sum of `SellQty` depending on `ItemID` for `Form → DGv2` and update the value of `SellQty` in  `DGV1`.

Example: `For ItemID=1  sum(SellQty)=40`

so I need to assign this value to `DGV1 SellQty Column=40`.

Please advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following will give you total quantity for `ItemID == 1` - *(make sure you use the correct column names for your datagrid)*

```
int total = DGV1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Where(r=> Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["ItemID"].Value) == 1)
                    .Sum(t=> Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SellQty"].Value));
```

EDIT:

For your updating gridview you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["ItemID"].Value) == 1)
        DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["SellQty"] = total;
}
```

Comment: Hi...I am getting the sum for a particular ID by looping thru gridview and using datatable                                  object Value = dtBatchSellQty.Compute("Sum(SellQty)", "BatchItemID='" + ItemID.ToString() + "'");
sum = Convert.ToInt32(Value);  My question How to assign this value to the SellQty column of the DGV1 cell where ItemID=1

Comment: @user2002785, You can iterate the GridView Rows and set `SellQty` to total, but I believe your question to get the total using LINQ

Comment: Yeah Habib...i have used Linq now..to get the sum.But I didn't get how to set the value..as we need the rowIndex of the row where the ItemId is matching

Comment: @user2002785, why not have simple for loop and check where ItemId is 1 there update the value of cell like `DGV1.Rows[index].Cells["SellQty"] = total`

Comment: I am exactly trying the same..but not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code maybe usfull

```
Textbox.Text = (from dr in MyDataSet.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
              where !dr.IsCR_TRANSFER_AMTNull()
              select dr.CR_TRANSFER_AMTNull).Sum().ToString();
```

Comment: Hi...I am getting the sum for a particular ID by looping thru gridview and using datatable                                  object Value = dtBatchSellQty.Compute("Sum(SellQty)", "BatchItemID='" + ItemID.ToString() + "'");
sum = Convert.ToInt32(Value);  My question How to assign this value to the SellQty column of the DGV1 cell where ItemID=1

Answer (score 0):

Another version of linq from idea of Mr. Habib

```
var total = DGV1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
             .Where(c => int.Parse(c.Cells[IndeOfItemId].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()) == 1)
             .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Cells[IndexOfSellQty].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()));
```

Comment: Hi Spajce...We meet again..The problem is how to assign this value to the DGV1 SellQty cell where ItemId=1 or 2 or 3